# Program for efficient computation of given functional:

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, performance-tuning, special-functions, complex

I need to plot the following functional with accuracy:

$$
I(x,s) =\int_0^\infty\mathrm dy \frac{F(x + \mathrm iy,s) − F(x −\mathrm iy,s)}{\mathrm e^{2πy}-1},
$$
Where $ F(z,s) = \dfrac{1}{z^s\Gamma(\sin^2[π\Gamma(z)/(2z)])} $.

And let us restrict $s\in[0,1]$

> What is the most efficient way of computing this integral in Mathematica?

> What is the nature of functional as $x\rightarrow\infty$ from the computation ?

I computed some relatively small values  which suggest the function is oscillatory with damping. But I need big values greater than x=100 and at s=1

Comment: Are you trying to use the [Abel-Plana formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel–Plana_formula)?

Comment: @J.M. yes sir $\phantom{}$

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: @MichaelE2 I completely agree with you sir. But as you can see the code is simple but my computations doesn't agree with expected results. So I'm asking here without mentioning anything i.e. from scratch.

Comment: It was just some advice, meant to be helpful, for getting more people to try out your integral.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thank you sir

Answer (score 2):

Here's a start you may wish to work with:

```
(*
  define f
*)
myF[z_, s_] := 1/(z^s Gamma[Sin[(Pi Gamma[z])/(2 z)]^2])
(*
 define the integrand
*)
integrand[z_, s_] := (myF[z, s] - myF[Conjugate[z], s])/( 
 Exp[2 Pi Im@z] - 1)
(*
  define integral expression in terms of z=x+Iy and real 0<s<1
  note dz=Idy in the expression for integrating with respect
  to y for z=x+I y
*)
myInt[x_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[I integrand[z, s] /. z -> x + I y, {y, 0, 4}]
(*
 Plot Real (red) and Im (blue) component of integral function for
s=1/4 integrating from 1 to 2
*)
Plot[{Re@myInt[x, 1/4], Im@myInt[x,1/4]}, {x, 1, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer sir but the integral is from zero to infinity and answer should be only in real domain as the functions in functional deals with real valued functions.

Comment: Why have you got an `I` in front of `integrand[z, s]` in `myInt`? Also, in the plot, I think you are computing `myInt[x, 1/4]` twice. You could divide the computation time by 2 using `ReIm` (see also `ReImPlot`).

Comment: The i is in the integral because the integrand is f(z)dz and letting z=x+iy with x constant in integrating with respect to y we have dz=idy and  the integral becomes i f(z(y))dy